# After ingesting data into Memgraph, I don't want to modify it anymore - what should I do?

Tags: memgraphdb

After ingesting data into Memgraph, I don't want to modify it anymore. As far as I understand, manually creating a snapshot and then setting the storage mode to Analytical should speed up my queries. Are there any reasons not to do this if I want to use the DB in read-only mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, Analytical storage mode will speed up your queries and you are 100% save to use it if there will be no writes (read-only queries).